# CouchDB boolean filtering

Tags: couchdb, couchbase-lite, couchdb-futon

I am trying to work with `CouchDB` [filtering](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/ddocs.html) but I can not understand how it works

So lets say, like the example they have:

```
function(doc, req){
    // we need only `mail` documents
    if (doc.type != 'mail'){
        return false;
    }
    // we're interested only in `new` ones
    if (doc.status != 'new'){
        return false;
    }
    return true; // passed!
}
```

I am bit confused because if I want to return only

> mail documents

I think I should implement something like:

```
 if (doc.type == 'mail'){
        return true;
    }
```

At the end we have

> return true //passed

but, is that mean that I will return all the documnents I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example doesn't just filter for mail documents, it also requires they be new.  Without the "new document check" you could just as well write the code as

```
function(doc, req){
  // we need only `mail` documents
  if (doc.type == 'mail') {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

The whole logic of the original, though, is implementing (in pseudo-code)

```
if (!mail document or !new document) then false
else true
```